# Swagger does not publish assets files in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, swagger

i have installed laravel 5.6 with Swagger with DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger package, i have followed the installation instructions that is

> php composer require "darkaonline/l5-swagger:5.6.*"
>
> php artisan vendor:publish --provider
>   "L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider"

i have also set

> L5_SWAGGER_GENERATE_ALWAYS=true

in my env and created a controller and added

```
/**
 * @SWG\Swagger(
 *     schemes={"http","https"},
 *     host="api.host.com",
 *     basePath="/",
 *     @SWG\Info(
 *         version="1.0.0",
 *         title="This is my website cool API",
 *         description="Api description...",
 *         termsOfService="",
 *         @SWG\Contact(
 *             email="contact@mysite.com"
 *         ),
 *         @SWG\License(
 *             name="Private License",
 *             url="URL to the license"
 *         )
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\ExternalDocumentation(
 *         description="Find out more about my website",
 *         url="http..."
 *     )
 * )
 */
```

after that i typed

```
php artisan l5-swagger:generate
php artisan vendor:publish
```

when i visit /api/documentation i get a white screen and in the console i am getting the following error

[image]

your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue and could not found any solution still now...

Answer (score 10):

I have fixed that issue by steps:

just copied files from vendor folder and added in the specific path.

Copy all the files from : laravel-yourapp\vendor\swagger-api\swagger-ui\dist

Then paste all files in path:  laravel-yourapp\public\docs\asset

Answer (score 0):

1 - try to copy the `/dist` directory in `\vendor\swagger-api\swagger-ui`  to `\public_html\swagger-api\`

2 - change  `"swagger_ui_assets_path"` address from `\config\l5-swagger.php` to `'public_html\swagger-api\'`

3 - change all links in **link** and **script** tag in view file `\resources\views\vendor\l5-swagger\index.blade.php`

4- type command `php artisan l5-swagger:generate` or add `L5_SWAGGER_GENERATE_ALWAYS=true` in **.env** file

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel 8. The documentation says that it uses a package auto-discovery feature. But it's not true.

You have to add to your config/app.php in the providers section:

```
L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider::class,
```

Then, you have to run the

```
php artisan config:cache
```

And only then, you can run the

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider 'L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use common settings for nginx:

```
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    expires max;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Need add:

```
location ~ (^/docs/asset/.*) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    expires max;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Or `wait - https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/pull/503`

Answer (score 0):

For darkaonline/l5-swagger 8.5 and above copy the content of the folder vendor/swagger-api/swagger-ui/dist into public/docs/asset

Answer (score -2):

After Debugging i have found that the error was coming when i was accessing the the swagger page via an open localhost port eg http://localhost:8000/api/documentation , the solution is to access it via the full laravel url eg http://localhost/my-app-name/public/api/documentation